# How to get values from one array based on another array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So, I am trying to figure out a situation where I would populate an array (`b[]`) with the index numbers from another array (`a[]`) whose elements meet a certain criteria (array `b` would be index numbers based on array `a` which is an array of images, and would populate `b` when width is greater than height).

So, I came up with a hypothetical function in hopes of getting an array output where I would get a listing from `a[]` that align with values from `b[]`. Needless to say, neither attempt came up with anything of value.

```
var a = ['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef', 'fg', 'gh', 'hi'];
var b = [2, 4, 5];


var d = function(a, b) {
  var func1 = [];
  var func2 = [];

  for(i = 0; i > b.length; i++) {
    func1.push(a[b[i]]);
  }

  console.log('func1 = ' + func1); // 'func1 = []'

  for(i=0; i > a.length; i++) {
    if(b.indexOf(a.indexOf(a[i])) > -1) {
      func2.push(a[i])
    }
  }
  console.log('func2 = ' + func2); // 'func2 = []'
}


d(a,b) // Ideally outputs ['cd', 'ef', 'fg']
```

Is this a matter of function scope, or am I missing the point of `.push`?

Comment: use "<" instead of ">" in your for loops

Comment: That was awfully derpy of me.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparisons in your for loops are backwards. They should be like this:

```
for(i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    func1.push(a[b[i]]);
  }

  console.log('func1 = ' + func1); // 'func1 = []'

  for(i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(b.index(a.indexOf(a[i])) > 1) {
      func2.push(a[i])
    }
  }
```

Also, b.index is not a function. I assume you meant indexOf:

```
var a = ['ab', 'bc', 'cd', 'de', 'ef', 'fg', 'gh', 'hi'];
var b = [2, 4, 5];


var d = function(a, b) {
  var func1 = [];
  var func2 = [];

  for(i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
    func1.push(a[b[i]]);
  }

  console.log('func1 = ' + func1); // 'func1 = []'

  for(i=0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if(b.indexOf(a.indexOf(a[i])) > 1) {
      func2.push(a[i])
    }
  }
  console.log('func2 = ' + func2); // 'func2 = []'
}


d(a,b) // Ideally outputs ['cd', 'ef', 'fg']
```

This outputs:

```
func1 = cd,ef,fg
func2 = fg
```

Comment: It was meant to be `if(b.indexOf(a.indexOf(a[i])) > -1)`.  In terms of efficiency, is `func1` better than `func2` since it has less loops to go through?

Answer (score 0):

use `for(i=0; i < a.length; i++)` instead!  Proper syntax is the key to success!  Thanks @Superdrac